# Reusable component access child method in parent slot

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Say I have a component `Reusable` with a method `onClick` that sets a data prop. I want this component to be reusable, and I want to use slots to override parts.

As I understand the canon, I must pass the `onClick` method as a scoped property up to `parent` from `reusable`:

```
<div class="reusable">
    <h2>Reusable</h2>
    <slot name="clicker" v-bind:onClick="onClick">
        Default stuff <button v-on:click="onClick">Close</button>
    </slot>
    <p v-if="clicked">You clicked me</p>
</div>

<div class="parent">
    <h1>Parent</h1>
    <reusable>
        <template slot="clicker" scope="reusable">
            <button click="reusable.onClick">
                Close from parent
            </button>
        </template>
    </reusable>
</div>
```

This might get verbose and noisy if I have a lot of methods, and I wondered: **is there a better way**, or is this entirely cromulent?

*I've looked at using refs, and having methods on the parent call `this.$refs.reusable.onClick`, as well as specifying dynamic components and swapping them out; both seem counterintuitive.*

Comment: I think you want to handle `onClick` event from *child* component in *parent* component, Is that correct?

Comment: @ironcladgeek I believe `parent` is the parent here, and `reusable` is rendered with `parent`s scope as a child: hence why I can't just bind `onClick`. The `parent` component doesn't need to know anything about `reusable`, it just wants to override parts of it. I should say: the example above works, I just want to know if it's the *correct* way of doing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could bind the slot's properties using object notation:

```
<slot name="clicker" v-bind="{ onClick, onInput, onCustom }">
    Default stuff <button v-on:click="onClick">Close</button>
</slot>
```

[Here's a working fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/ev1nboko/1/)

---

And if that gets to be too verbose you could at least move the object definition to the data properties and get it out of the template:

```
<slot name="clicker" v-bind="scopeProps">
    Default stuff <button v-on:click="onClick">Close</button>
</slot>
```

```javascript
data() {
  return {
    scopeProps: {
      onClick: this.onClick,
      onInput: this.onInput,
      onCustom: this.onCustom
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: OK, so it seems this is The Correct way to do it, and this certainly makes it a bit less painful. It really is just a case of being explicit with your component slots scope.

Comment: One caveat worth mentioning on the `scopeProps` is that you'll obviously lose `data`, so it might make more sense to collect methods etc. therein and call it `scopeMethods` or similar.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "lose `data`". The slot's scope will only have available what you explicitly assign to it.

Comment: If `data` has `{ message: 'Hello', scopeProps: { onClick: this.onClick } }` then we don't have `message` without changing the `v-bind` to something like `{ message: message, scopeMethods: scopeProps }` super small caveat.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say we have 2 components named *`reusable`* and *`parent`*.

**reusable.vue**:

```js
<template>
  <div class="reusable">
      <h2>Reusable</h2>
      <slot name="clicker">
          Default stuff <button v-on:click="handleClick">Close</button>
      </slot>
      <p v-if="clicked">You clicked me</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  params: {
    onClick: {
      type: Function,
      default() {}
    }
  }
  
  methods: {
    handleClick() {
      // default codes to execute goes here
      // then call onClick() callback
      this.onClick();
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**parent.vue**

```js
<template>
  <div class="parent">
      <h1>Parent</h1>
      <reusable :on-click="onClickHandler">
          <template slot="clicker">
              // other codes for injecting to slot
          </template>
      </reusable>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import reusable from './path/to/reusable.vue';

export default {
  components: { reusable },
  
  methods: {
    onClickHandler() {
      // stuff to be run when button in 'reusable' got clicked
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

This is one possible solution for your use case.

Comment: I don't think this solves the problem: we've reimplemented `onClick` within parent, which I think is unnecessary. I think the parent template needs to call that method directly on `reusable`.